# How to define constant where scope is limited locally within module

Tags: python

How will I convey to other developer that particular constant is designed to be used locally within module ?

Consider below example from MyScript.py

```
PATH='Some configurable path'
```

How will I define PATH constant where scope is limited locally within particular module. Does it has to be prefixed with double underscore ?

Comment: What does this mean? All scope is limited.

Comment: There is no way in python to limit the scope of a variable. There is nothing as constant at all in python. Just comment in the module that you dont import this constant OR Define a class in the module in which you define these constants and define functions to get these constants.

Comment: @gautamaggarwal Agree with your comment. However I just want to understand how will I convey this to other developer that particular constant is designed to be used locally

Comment: Define a class in module with name as LocalConstants. Define getters functions to get these constants. Dont define the setters. That way it is clear that the variable values are not to be changed and comment. In python documentation is expected to be explicit.

Comment: @gautamaggarwal that's freaking overkill.  The answer is __way__ simpler: `ALL_UPPER` names are to considered as constants, and names starting with a single leading underscore are to be considered as private, so all the OP has to do is to name his variable `_PATH` and everyone will know it's a private constant.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yeah I agree. It is an overkill. My very first suggestion was to comment it and yes by usual convention, you do define it in capital letters. But that is all documentation, right? Mutual agreement between the matured ones. But He wanted a way to limit the scope in the module. So why not encapsulate the constant inside a class. That was just another suggestion, If he was way too serious.

Comment: @gautamaggarwal How using a class would "limit the scope" to the module ? There's no way to prevent anyone to access anything in Python.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers It does not!  But it does encapsulate the local constants together, right? Add a docstring defining the purpose of class. Name the class as LocalConstants. It is just a way of documenting. One could also define a dictionary with name LOCAL_CONSTANTS. The purpose is not to document constants only here, right? but also to give a message that these are meant to be local constants not to be used in other modules. True, You could just add a comment above the constants. But if you want to give a more serious message, You can choose latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just want to understand how will I convey this to other developer that particular constant is designed to be used locally

Then prefix it with a single underscore (=> `_PATH=...`). This is the convention to specify this name is not part of the public API (works for every kind of name - module-level, class or instance attributes etc).

This won't technically prevent anyone from using it (just like ALL_UPPER won't technically make it a constant) but as long as you respect this naming rule the intent is clear for every pythonista and anyone messing with it is on it's own.